# 'Config' object has no attribute 'jax_experimental_name_stack'

Tags: python, config, attributeerror

[Schreenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ktgw.png)

I'm trying to run Alphafold on Google runtime, and I'm getting this error:

```
UnfilteredStackTrace                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ca4ee2dc266d> in <module>
     44     processed_feature_dict = model_runner.process_features(np_example, random_seed=0)
---> 45     prediction = model_runner.predict(processed_feature_dict, random_seed=random.randrange(sys.maxsize))
     46 

UnfilteredStackTrace: AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'jax_experimental_name_stack'

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haiku/_src/module.py in wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
    406       f = functools.partial(unbound_method, self)
    407       f = functools.partial(run_interceptors, f, method_name, self)
--> 408       if jax.config.jax_experimental_name_stack and module_name:
    409         local_module_name = module_name.split("/")[-1]
    410         f = jax.named_call(f, name=local_module_name)

AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'jax_experimental_name_stack'
```

How do I resolve this error? The link for Alphafold is below.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepmind/alphafold/blob/main/notebooks/AlphaFold.ipynb

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On Stack Overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see [*How do I format my code blocks?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186). A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tri